# How old was Frodo when Bilbo Celebrated his 111th Birthday?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

In The Fellowship of the Ring, Bilbo was celebrated his 111th birthday. Then he gave the Ring to his nephew (Frodo Baggins), after being confronted confronted by his friend Gandalf the Grey. How old was Frodo at that time ?

Comment: This is such a low effort question. Its mentioned in the first few pages of the book and first few minutes of the movie.

Comment: It is, but not, IMO, deserving of a downvote

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr not to mention that "Frodo's age" on Google returns a huge '33'.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it can easily be answered with a simple google search.

Comment: @SSumner The tooltip for the downvote button says "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly did Orochimaru do to Naruto's kyuubi seal?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8862/what-exactly-did-orochimaru-do-to-narutos-kyuubi-seal)

Comment: @Mo1 ?? Was this a mistake?

Comment: Yes, thought I deleted it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

33

Remember that they "summed up 144 years" and that it was also the majority birthday for Frodo. This is all explicit in the book (no English quotable text at hand, mine is a translation).

> "Bilbo was going to be eleventy-one, 111, a rather curious number and a very respectable age for a hobbit (the Old Took himself had only reached 130); and Frodo was going to be thirty-three, 33) an important number: the date of his 'coming of age'." (From book 1 chapter 1)

Comment: 144 is also the sum of the (invited) guests: A dozen dozen (12*12=144) guests as Bilbo put it (above all he says that, because it's impolite to count Hobbits in dozens)

Comment: "Bilbo was going to be eleventy-one, 111, a rather curious number and a very respectable age for a hobbit (the Old Took himself had only reached 130); and Frodo was going to be thirty-three, 33) an important number: the date of his 'coming of age'." (From book 1 chapter 1)

Comment: Thanks for editing and adding the quote, Meat and Simon

Comment: @Einer AFAIR counting hobbits by the dozen wasn't what was offensive - it was using the term 'one gross' (and implying they were invited to pad out the numbers)

Comment: @HorusKol You might be right. Read the books in German translation. Maybe the gross / dozen aspect was lost then.

Comment: @Einer ah, yeah - translations can be so tricky at times

Answer (score 3):

The combined ages of Bilbo and Frodo were 144, therefore Frodo would have been 33 (they shared the same birthday, hence Bilbo referring to "Our Birthday.")  As Einer mentions this is a dozen dozen, in English this is a gross, but the word gross can also mean very rude or coarse, vulgar; when used as an adjective.  Thus some of the Hobbits taking offence at being referred to as a gross.

> The invitations were limited to twelve dozen (a number
>   also called by the hobbits one Gross, though the word was
>   not considered proper to use of people); and the guests were
>   selected from all the families to which Bilbo and Frodo were
>   related, with the addition of a few special unrelated friends
>   (such as Gandalf).
>
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* Book One, Chapter 1: *A Long-expected Party*</sub>

Comment: Have you got any reference for this?

Comment: The modern meaning of gross as something unpleasant didn't exist so this is incorrect. They were mildly objecting to being counted by the dozen, or gross, like eggs or bags or flour rather than individuals.